# Why is the normal distribution the only distribution where the sample mean and sample standard deviation are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Why is the normal distribution the only distribution where the sample mean $\bar{x}$ and sample standard deviation $s$ are independent? Does it have to do with the fact that normal distributions are parameterized by $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

And for that matter, how are the sample mean and $s$ independent in a normal distribution?? It seems intuitively clear the center ($\bar{x}$) and spread ($s$) of a sample should be independent; And yet, this independence is still strange when you consider that $\bar{x}$ shows up in the formula for sample $s$.

Another reason that it's surprising to me that $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are independent is that if you have a sample of size $n=50$ and you know $\bar{x}$ and 49 of the values, then the 50'th value can be computed.

Comment: If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables with $X_1\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb R, \sigma\ge 0$ (where $\sigma=0$ means that $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the Dirac distribution concentrated at $0$), then the sample mean
$$\bar X_n=\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$
and sample variance
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\bar X_n)^2$$
are stochastically independent for all $n\ge 2$. For a proof of this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203312

Comment: Cf. also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320972/248311 and https://jstor.org/stable/2236166 for a proof that this characterizes the normal distribution

Comment: Perhaps it would help to think about why you don't get independence for other distributions. For example, if you sample from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and you get a sample mean of .05, that tells you that your sample very likely had unusually low variance.

Comment: Also, the property doesn't follow from how the normal distribution is parameterized. Most families with two parameters could be parameterized this way. For example, you could specify a uniform distrbution by just giving $\mu$ and $\sigma$. (Giving you a distribution uniform over the interval $[\mu - \sqrt{3}\sigma, \mu + \sqrt{3}\sigma]$.)

Comment: Also $\mathcal N(\mu,0)$ is concentrated at $\mu$, not at $0$ (as incorrectly claimed in my comment above).